# Java SWT: 22 MB of runnable.jar file. Is it possible to reduce the size?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, executable-jar, windowbuilder

I'm developing an application with Java SWT and WindowBuilder.

I'm building with Eclipse and export to runnable .jar and I did organize imports before.

Now I'm testing to generate the runnable .jar file and I noticed that the .jar file has 22 MB of size. My classes are only a few kb and I don't use images or videos, so the 22 MB are from SWT libraries or something similar probably.

Exists a possibility to compact the .jar runnable file forcing it to contain just the necessary and used SWT or Java libraries? For sure now it's containing the full SWT package and a lot of stuff that I'm not using.

Comment: How are dependencies managed? How are you building the jar?

Comment: "The 22 MB are from SWT libraries or something similar probably." Without knowing exactly what's there, it's hard to recommend what to remove.

Comment: The SWT jar is only 2.1 MB so you are including some else that is large.

Comment: I'm building with Eclipse and export to runnable .jar and I did organize imports before

Answer (score 0):

Go to the projects build path configuration and remove unnecessary libraries.

I was able to create a *very* basic SWT program with only the platform specific org.eclipse.swt library.

It ended up being about 3mb total when I exported it as a runnable jar.

When the project was initially created (I used the WindowBuilder feature), it had a lot of Eclipse framework libraries included that were not necessary.

Comment: in which tab? Libraries? how can I know which of them will not be user by the project?

Comment: Yes, the Libraries tab. As for which libraries to remove, you'll have to use some logical deduction.  If you're JUST using SWT (as I did in my test), you can remove everything except the SWT library. If you're using any of the jface or other eclipse framework, you'll need to keep those libraries.

Comment: why are added if they are not being used? it's strange

Comment: They are probably being added because most people use more than just SWT.